# add transaction to function realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I'm trying to add a transaction to the function and it doesn't work

> error: The argument type 'Future<Null> Function(Object?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Transaction Function(Object?)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [karaoke] lib\pages\Firebase\RealTimeDatabase.dart:85)

```
Future<void> updateSong(String songName) async {
  String uid = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/'${uid}'");

  await ref.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    DataSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.once();
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> value = snapshot.value;

    // כאן אתה יכול לבצע שינויים במשתנה value על פי הצורך
    value["song"] = songName;

    transaction.update(ref, value);
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't think the callback for `runTransaction` can be `async`. But I also don't think it has a `once()` method, so I'm not sure how that line can compile either. :-/